# Import Large Excel File

Tags: import, excel

Currently, I am working on a large time series dataset, which **contains 928,586 rows and 35 time intervals in columns**, in excel format (.xlsx) and using `Import` to read it in.  Actually, I cannot use `Import` to handle this file since it gives me the Java heap error message: `Import::nojmem: There was insufficient Java heap space for the operation. Try increasing the Java Virtual Machine heap size.`

Here is only a part of my data after using `Import`.

```
data = {{"BRANCHNO", "Date", "JustDay", "JustDate", "JustMonth", "JustYear", 
  "DoM.Train", "DoM.Test", "Total TXN", "08:00:00", "08:30:00", 
  "09:00:00", "09:30:00", "10:00:00", "10:30:00", "11:00:00", 
  "11:30:00", "12:00:00", "12:30:00", "13:00:00", "13:30:00", 
  "14:00:00", "14:30:00", "15:00:00", "15:30:00", "16:00:00", 
  "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", 
  "19:00:00", "19:30:00", 
  "20:00:00"}, {"B0001", {2011, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, "Tuesday", 4., 
  "January", 2011., 4., 4., 1538., 47., 59., 71., 77., 115., 111., 
  103., 75., 101., 121., 135., 113., 82., 88., 79., 72., 54., 13., 
  21., 1., "", "", "", "", ""}, {"B0001", {2011, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 
  "Wednesday", 5., "January", 2011., 5., 5., 1589., 20., 51., 33., 
  68., 97., 82., 101., 78., 104., 119., 137., 109., 114., 142., 85., 
  77., 62., 40., 51., 19., "", "", "", "", 
  ""}, {"B0001", {2011, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, "Thursday", 6., "January", 
  2011., 6., 6., 1399., 3., 39., 61., 59., 63., 108., 66., 85., 108., 
  119., 114., 121., 94., 80., 62., 88., 56., 46., 16., 9., "", "", 2.,
   "", ""}, {"B0001", {2011, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, "Friday", 7., "January",
   2011., 7., 7., 1510., 13., 55., 74., 70., 105., 95., 71., 82., 86.,
   113., 124., 91., 98., 76., 112., 84., 78., 64., 18., 1., "", "", 
  "", "", ""}}
```

I am wondering that:

1. How can I import this file ?
2. What is the best way to handle excel file ?
3. After importing the excel file, can we save the data in other format (like MATLAB can save in .mat file) so that next time we can import it faster ?

Thanks for help