# Writing results directly to file

Tags: graphs-and-networks, memory, files-and-directories

I am trying to find all simple paths in a large directed graph (542 vertex, density ~ 5%) between two nodes. For this purpose, I use the algorithm from [this thread.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/finding-all-simple-paths-between-two-vertices-in-a-graph) Unfortunately, my computer is running out of memory during this operation. I was thinking it would help to write the paths found directly to a text file, but I don't know how to do it in this case. Maybe, you'll have other suggestions as well. [Here's the file](http://yadi.sk/d/pC61MfvmJjc9U) with the adjacency matrix.

```
SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\crazyfrog\\Documents\\ДИПЛОМ"];
findPaths[a_?MatrixQ, s_Integer, t_Integer] := 
  Module[{child, find}, 
   child[v_] := Flatten@Position[a[[v]], Except@0, 1, Heads -> False];
   find[v_, list_] := 
    Scan[If[# === t, Sow[Append[list, #]], 
       If[FreeQ[list, #], find[#, Append[list, #]]]] &, child@v];
   If[# =!= {}, First@#, {}] &@Last@Reap@find[s, {s}]];
findPaths[g_Graph, s_, t_] := 
  Module[{nodes = VertexList@g, convert}, 
   convert = Thread[nodes -> Range@Length@nodes];
   findPaths[Normal@AdjacencyMatrix@g, s /. convert, t /. convert] /. 
    Reverse /@ convert];
<< JLink`;
InstallJava[];
ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx1024m"]; data = 
 Import["test.xlsx"][[1]]; data2 = Round[data];
g = AdjacencyGraph[data2];
$HistoryLength = 0; findPaths[g, 1, 542] >> "result.txt"
```

Comment: `Import`'s failure to read even modestly large excel files is a well known bug. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42081/import-large-excel-file  Best bet save your data in some intermediate format such as csv.

Comment: just to check, i'd advise putting your last 4 statements into separate cells so that you can clearly see where the error arises.

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for you idea but excel file is imported sucessfully. The problem occurs when I try to find all paths

Comment: break your last statement into seperate cells as as `res=findP...` amd `res>>file` and post the *exact* error message.

Comment: @george2079 did what you said, and after ~3 hours: "No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry."

Comment: i wanted to sort out which step is causing the problem..i'd assume the calculation not the write. looks like you have an answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to write the results to file as they are found. I can't be sure if this will solve your memory problem as I have not run it for long enough.

The original code uses `Sow` to collect the results. All that is required is to replace `Sow` with a `Write` statement, plus code to open and close the file stream.

I have also made a couple of other minor changes:

- I converted the XLSX file to CSV (in Excel) so that it can be loaded without mucking about with the Java stack size.
- I didn't see any point in importing an adjacency matrix, converting it to a graph, and then feeding it into a function which converts it back to an adjacency matrix. So I used just the matrix version of `findPaths`.
- I call the recursive `find` function inside a `Block` with `$RecursionLimit` set to infinity, to allow for paths of any length.

.

```
data = Import["test.csv"];

writePaths[a_?MatrixQ, s_Integer, t_Integer, file_] :=
 Module[{child, find, stream},
  stream = OpenWrite[file];
  child[v_] := Flatten@Position[a[[v]], Except@0, 1, Heads -> False];
  find[v_, list_] := Scan[If[# === t,
      Write[stream, Append[list, #]],
      If[FreeQ[list, #], find[#, Append[list, #]]]] &, child@v];
  Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, find[s, {s}]];
  Close[stream]]

writePaths[data, 1, 542, "paths.txt"];
```